# Reducing cubes of image to single vector using PCA

Tags: matlab, pca

This is a following up question to my previous question about PCA (so the beginning is the same but the question is different).

I have a 4D image of size 90 x 60 x 12 x 350. That means that each voxel is a vector of size 350 (time series).

Now I divide the 3D image (90 x 60 x 12) into cubes. So let's say a cube contains n voxels, so I have n vectors of size 350. I want to reduce this n vectors to only one vector and then calculate the correlations between all vectors of all cubes.

So for a cube I can construct the matrix M where I just put each voxel after each other, i.e. M = [v1 v2 v3 ... vn] and each v is of size 350.

Now the problem is that the cubes are not all of the same size, that means at the borders they are smaller. This implies that the first column of coeff is of different size. But I need it all of the same size because I want to calculate the correlations later.

How should I correct this? Should I just add zero vectors to M so that each cube is of the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ignore the cubes intersected by the border
- Take the cubes touching the border from the inside and merge them with the overlapping parts of the other cubes

Comment: How would you do the merging?

Comment: I think I'd use some average. Admittedly it's not very elegant.

Comment: Perhaps study deblocking algorithms for getting similar ideas.